# Http responses are not recorded when using npm replay package?

Tags: node.js, npm, replay

I'm trying to use npm replay package to record the http responses while integration testing. I am using chai and mocha. This is my code:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var supertest = require('supertest');
var express = require('express');
var expect = chai.expect;
var replay  = require('replay');

var assert  = require('assert');
var HTTP    = require('http');
var primary = require('./data/primary.json');

describe('Server Tests', function() {

    beforeEach(function(){
        replay.localhost('127.0.0.1:3978');
    });

    it('should run the replay module', function(done) {
        supertest('http://localhost:3978')
            .post('/api/messages')
            .send(primary)
            .end(function (err, response) {
                console.log(response);
               expect(response.statusCode).to.eq(202);
               //expect(response.body).to.eq("Oxymoron 2. Exact estimate\n\n[codehappy] http://iheartquotes.com/fortune/show/38021\n");
                console.log('Woot!');
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

Also, I get the correct response status code.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the call to `relay.localhost`. From the docs:

> You can tell node-replay what hosts to treat as "localhost". Requests to these hosts will be routed to 127.0.0.1, without capturing or replay.